# Display message after custom button confirmation

Tags: apex, visualforce, code

I have created a custom button and i need to have a "Record created successfully" and redirect to the newly created record after clicking yes on the confirmation.
I have returned the message from my class but it does not display. 
Anything that I might forget/overlooked? Thanks

```
Error message: Respond is not defined.
```

This is my custom button

```
confirm("Continue?");
var resultMsg = sforce.apex.execute("convertProject","OppId", 
{oID:"{!Opportunity2__c.Id}"});

alert(respond)
window.location.reload()
```

This is the snippet of class

```
Project__c newProj = new Project__c(
              Name = OppName +' - Project ',

              newProject.add(newProj);

              respond = 'Successfully created a new Project';
          }

          else{
              respond = 'You cannot create a project';
              return respond;
            }

         }

        if(newProject.size()>0){
           insert newProject;

         }      
          return respond;   
  }
```

Comment: change your alert from 'respond' to 'resultmsg'.

Comment: hi @AbhishekDaware, the error message persists, resultmsg is not defined

Comment: I hope you type resultMsg like this only

Comment: If you still facing an issue then paste your apex class code. I will verify and modify the same.

Comment: @AbhishekDaware I have created an if statement checking if resultmsg is null  and alert(resultmsg) works. Is it possible to redirect to the newly created project record?

Comment: Yes, we can do that but for that, you need change your logic a bit. Instead of returning the error message return the record Id and validate the error message on that basis. If record Id id return then just add a line window.location.href = '/'+recordId;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try below code to display message.

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT('/soap/ajax/41.0/connection.js')} 
{!REQUIRESCRIPT('/soap/ajax/41.0/apex.js')} 

var retVal = confirm("Do you want to continue ?");
if (retVal == true)
{
    var resultMsg = sforce.apex.execute("convertProject","OppId", 
    {oID:"{!Opportunity2__c.Id}"});

    if( resultMsg != null) { 
       alert(resultMsg ); 
    } 
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Hi, @ravikant, if I click Cancel, resultmsg still displays

Comment: I have updated the code please check.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I added if on IF(confirm("Do you want to continue ?") ){}. Is it possible to redirect to the newly created record?